# Does dataframe' method iterrows skip rows?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am using this code below to iterate over my dataframe data

```py
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    print(index)
```

And I have this output :

```
    0
    1
    3
    4
    5
    7
    8
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    17
    18
    19
    20
    22
    23
    25
    27
    28
    30
```

It skips `2, 6, 16, 21, 24`, and `26`.
Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Are 2, 6, 16, 21, 24, or 26 actually present in your dataframe's index?

Comment: Maybe your data frame does not contain those indices?

Comment: If you have done any data filters before this step, you might forgot to reset index, you can do it by `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: as the other comments are eluding to, A dataframe's index does **NOT** necessarily have to  be ordered.  You most certainly augmented the index prior to this step.

Comment: Yes you were all right, I used filters before executing that loop so the indexes are not present in the dataframe's index and that was affecting my treatment over some rows executing `df.reset_index(drop=True)` worked out for me. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through your index values, so there could be gaps due to many factors such as preprocessing and drop of rows containing NaNs.
One thing you can do is reset your index to default row numbers

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

drop=True will drop your old index, in most of cases it is useless.